# How do I load an image to pdf (from a URL string) using PDFSharp namespace

Tags: c#, image, url, pdf, pdfsharp

I'm trying to create 1 master pdf from a list of pdf's from various URLs.  I am using the PDFSharp namespace for the first time and I'm having trouble finding any good documentation on it as far as classes, members, etc., so I appreciate your help!  I've created the following short little method to create my "Master PDF":

```
public PdfDocument CreateFinalPDF(PdfPage[] pages)
{
    PdfDocument m_pdfFinalCutSheet = new PdfDocument(m_sFileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.Length; i ++)
    {
        m_pdfFinalCutSheet.AddPage(pages[i]);
    }
    return m_pdfFinalCutSheet;    
}
```

I'm pretty sure that will work to compile everything, but the issue I'm having is loading the images to the `PdfPage[]`.  I need to do this from other PDF's that are located at URL's that I will have stored in a `List<string>`.

I was looking at the `PdfPage.AddWebLink` but I feel like that's just going to add a link to a URL (based on my astute deduction skills from the names of methods) rather than pulling an image from one.  Any insight or help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: [Samples](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx) page suggest that you can draw from file only. Download images from url first and then use the samples

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Let me elaborate:  I'm primarily trying to extract the images from a list of URL's, and put those images in to an array of images.  After I have the array of PDF images, I'm going to compile them in to 1 "master .pdf"

Comment: I'm currently placing the images in Bitmap's, but the file size is way too large - hence the PDF's.  My question is how load the image from the URL in to the PDF in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFsharp can use local files and streams, but cannot work with files on the Internet (remote URLs).

So you need code that downloads the files from the URLs to make them usable with PDFsharp.

Your assumption about `AddWebLink` is correct.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually wrote a function to download images from URLs and store it to an `Image` variable that I then put in to a PDF page.

Comment: I get this now:

    
`Could not load file or assembly 'PdfSharp, Version=1.32.3057.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`


You wouldn't happen to have an idea on how to fix this, would you?

Comment: Install PDFsharp properly and add references where needed. I recommend using Version 1.50 (latest pre-release). You can use the NuGet package and let Visual Studio install it for you.

Comment: In Visual Studio, the latest version is 1.32.3057.  Would it be a correct assumption that 1.50 would be available on their website?

Comment: The latest version on NuGet is 1.50 beta 3b. In order to see beta versions in Visual Studio, tick the prerelease checkbox.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh...  Thanks!  I'm new the this NuGet thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the assembly part: Generate the master PDF from the set of images, e.g. via a [PHP script] (https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520422-How-to-generate-a-multi-paged-PDF-from-images-in-my-account-)

Comment: the assembly of the master is not the problem.  I need to be able to get the set of images in the first place.